# ADO Linking requirement & test case work items with Rest API issue

Tags: rest, curl, azure-devops

I'm trying to link a ADO Requirement work item to a ADO Test Case work item. I'm making this call:

```
curl -u :********** -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json"  -H "Accept: application/json-patch+json" -d "[{{\"op\": \"test\", \"path\": \"/rev\",\"value\": 3 },{\"op\": \"add\", \"path\": \"/relations/-\", \"value\":\"{\"rel\": \"System.LinkTypes.Dependency-forward\",\"url\": \"https://***.***.com/{Organisation}/_apis/wit/workItems/{ID}\",\"attributes\": {\"comment\": \"Making a new link for the dependency\"}}}}]" https://***.***.com/{Organisation}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{ID}?api-version=6.0
```

as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#add-a-link

But I'm having this error:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must pass a valid patch document in the body of the request.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, the JSON was badly parse. I used a online JSON linter to fix it. https://jsonlint.com/

```
curl -u :********** -X PATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json"  -H "Accept: application/json-patch+json" -d "[{\"op\": \"add\", \"path\": \"/relations/-\", \"value\":{\"rel\": \"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.TestedBy-Forward\",\"url\": \"https://***.***.com/{Organisation}/_apis/wit/workItems/{ID}\",\"attributes\": {\"comment\": \"Making a new link for the dependency\"}}}]" https://***.***.com/{Organisation}/{Project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{ID}?api-version=6.0
```